# Run-time error message 91 (object variable not set)

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code in Excel VBA (using Excel 2010), to find a specific date, in the European format (dd/mm/yyyy), and then cancel the rows below the cell (with that date in it):

```
Sub Macro1()

' Macro1
Dim A As Variant

' Input box to insert a date
A = InputBox("Insert date of the last entry with format dd/mm/yyyy", "User date", Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
If IsDate(A) Then
    A = Format(CDate(A), "dd/mm/yyyy")
Else
    MsgBox "Date in the wrong format!"
End If

'Find the date above, in the variable A, in the Excel sheet
Cells.Find(What:=A, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

However, when I run the macro, I get the run-time error message 91

> object variable not set.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: If the range being searched contains actual dates (not text) then you need to search with the date, not a string representation.  `Cells.Find(What:=CDate(A), `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appears because `Find` method didn't return any result, yet you try to activate this not existing range in the same line.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim A As Variant
Dim foundRNG As Range
'
' Macro1
'
' Input box to insert a date

A = InputBox("Insert date of the last entry with format dd/mm/yyyy", "User date", Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
If IsDate(A) Then
    A = Format(CDate(A), "dd/mm/yyyy")
Else
    MsgBox "Date in the wrong format!"
End If

'Find the date above, in the variable A, in the Excel sheet

Set foundRNG = Cells.Find(What:=A, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If foundRNG Is Nothing = False Then
    foundRNG.Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Else
    MsgBox "Entered date not found!"
End If

End Sub
```